# Activate a minor mode switching off the other ones in a set of minor modes

Tags: variables, quote, setq

I'm developing a set of minor modes that I use in my LaTeX copy-editing work.

I have, e.g.. a list of three minor modes stored in a variable:

```el
(defvar latex-editing-mode
  '(preamble-editing-mode
    biblio-editing-mode
    proofs-editing-mode))
```

I need them to be active **one at a time**. E.g. when I turn-on `biblio-editing-mode` the other two modes must be turned-off.

I'm trying to write a function:

```el
(defun activate-mode-in-list (MINOR_MODE MINOR_MODE_LIST)      
  (interactive)
  (let ((MINOR_MODE_LIST (delete MINOR_MODE MINOR_MODE_LIST)))

(mapcar (lambda (mode) (setq mode nil)) MINOR_MODE_LIST)
(setq MINOR_MODE t)))
```

I need to use it this way:

```el
(activate-mode-in-list biblio-editing-mode latex-editing-mode)
```

because I want to use it to write a set of functions to be called with dedicated and consistent keybindings. Eg.

```el
(defun activate-biblio-editing-mode ()
  "Activate `biblio-editing-mode` and deactivate the other ones
setted in the `latex-editing-mode` variable"
  (interactive)
  (activate-mode-in-list biblio-editing-mode latex-editing-mode))
```

And then:

```el
(require 'preamble-editing-mode)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-kp-0>") 'activate-preamble-editing-mode)

(require 'biblio-editing-mode)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-kp-1>") 'activate-biblio-editing-mode)

;; ...

(require 'proofs-editing-mode)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-kp-9>") 'activate-proofs-editing-mode)
```

But my `activate-mode-in-list` function doesn't work as I wrote it. I guess I'm getting lost in quoting stuff because evaluating:

```el
(setq preamble-editing-mode nil)
(setq biblio-editing-mode t)
```

works as expected.

1. Where am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

All I need is a function that activates a specific minor-mode and deactivate some other minor modes. I can store this set of minor modes in a variable.. In my workflow, "in most cases", only one minor mode of this set of minor modes should be active at a time (but in some cases I would have more then one active at the same time. In this case I'd open them in the standard way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare this.  The essential difference is using `set` instead of `setq`.

```lisp
(defun activate-mode-in-list (minor-mode minor-mode-list)
  (dolist (mm  minor-mode-list)
    (set mm (eq mm minor-mode))))
```

Your feeling that *"I'm getting lost in quoting stuff because evaluating"* was not far off.  You don't want to set the values of the *local* variables `mode` (bound by `lambda`) and `minor-mode` (bound by `let`).  You want to set the *values of the variables* that those local variables are bound to.

The code I show here uses `set` to set the value of the value of local variable `mm`, which is one of your minor-mode variables, to `t` or `nil`, depending on whether that minor-mode variable is the input value, `minor-mode`.

E.g., for input `minor-mode` = `proofs-editing-mode`, during iteration, when `mm` is `proofs-editing-mode` we `set` the value of the symbol that is the value of `mm`, that is, `proofs-editing-mode`, to `t` (which is `(eq proofs-editing-mode proofs-editing-mode)`). Then when `mm` is, say, `biblio-editing-mode`, we `set` the value of `mm`, that is, `biblio-editing-mode`, to `nil` (which is `(eq biblio-editing-mode proofs-editing-mode)`).

Comment: I get this error: `let: Attempt to set a constant symbol: nil`

Comment: All I need is a function that activates a specific minor-mode and deactivate some other minor modes. I can store this set of minor modes in a variable.. In my workflow, "in most cases", only one minor mode of this set of minor modes should be active at time (but in some cases I would have more then one active at the same time. In this case i'd open them in the standard way).

Comment: I restored my original title because it is the very topic of my question. I tried to solve with the exaple i posted but maybe I'm doing the wrong way.

Comment: I get no error, using your `defvar` and inputting at the prompts (1) the name of one of your  `(preamble|biblio|proofs)-editing-mode` and (2) `latex-editing-mode`. `M-x activate...` then does exactly what you requested.

Comment: My foult. I don't need to call it interactively but in this way: `(activate-mode-in-list biblio-editing-mode latex-editing-mode)`. I update my question to better explain my purpose.

Comment: With the code I wrote, just use `(activate-mode-in-list 'biblio-editing-mode latex-editing-mode)`. None of the elements in your list is the *value* of any of those variables.

Comment: Modifing the code you proposed I managed to make it work this way: `(activate-mode-in-list "biblio-editing-mode" "latex-editing-mode")`. But I'd prefer to use the symbols as arguments, not the strings.

Comment: You aren't using the symbols as args if you use, as you said, `(activate-mode-in-list biblio-editing-mode latex-editing-mode)`. If you do that you're passing the *values* of those variables. And you can't delete the *value* of one of those variables from the value of `latex-editing-mode` because that value is a list of symbols (variables). You're confusing a variable, which is a symbol, with its value.

Comment: You're right. I'm getting lost. Indeed now the function activates the minor-mode in the first arg but does not deactivate the other ones.

Comment: Ok, finally it works but you missed a `copy-sequence` otherwise the list will be destroyed.

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep using the list then you either need to copy before deleting an element or (which is more common) just iterate over it instead of deleting anything. I took that deletion from your original code (before your edit). I tried to show your error in using `setq` instead of `set`. Looked at as that narrow misunderstanding it was a useful Q&A. Now it's not so useful, IMO. This really has nothing to do with minor modes etc.

Comment: Many thanks. I understand. Please feel free to edit the question and the title as you believe can better help other people. I chosen the deleting the method because it's easier to me to write the lambda function.

Comment: I've simplified the code, hopefully making things clearer. There's no reason to copy `latex-editing-mode` or to `delete` anything from any list (overtly). It's enough to iterate over the list and do what you want for each of its members.

Comment: Thank you! I'll study carefully your  code.